# Lost passport replacement visa application documents

Tags: visas, lost-documents

As you had explained to someone in an earlier post, I had submitted the required documents as listed in the thread (I was specifically asked for my lost passport photos, police report, etc.).

I submitted all these documents on January 25, and when I called the support service they said my mail has been submitted to the appropriate division of the embassy and it is not their job to reply.

Would you happen to know how long they usually take to reply as I have to get a passport immediately?

Thanks for taking the time to read this. Looking forward to your response.

Comment: You will need to link the other question you are referring to, as you are posting under a guest account which doesn't have your other question in its history, so no one knows what you are talking about based on this current question alone.  You risk having this question closed because its currently unclear what your question actually is.